# file not recognized: File format not recognized error in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Hey I am currently learning C and tried to divide my code in multiple files. But when it comes to compile the project, I got this error :

```
    mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g  -c D:\IDE\CodeBlocks\Projects\Tuto\main.c -o obj\Debug\main.o
    mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\Tuto.exe obj\Debug\dico.o dico.h.gch obj\Debug\main.o   
    dico.h.gch: file not recognized: File format not recognized
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried to clean and/or rebuild my project but nothing goes through this issue. Can anyone help me please ??

Comment: What is `dico.h.gch`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dico.h.gch` is a precompiled header. You aren't supposed to link it with your objects. Remove it from the line that creates `Tuto.exe`.

Comment: My god idk why I have been that stupid, thank you for pointing this out !